# Conditions for finite groups and its normal subgroup such that its complement is unique up to conjugation.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am aware of some examples of finite groups $G$ and its normal subgroup $N$ for which the complement of $N$ in $G$ is not unique up to conjugation. For example: Let $G = C_p \times C_p = \langle a,b\rangle$ with $N = \langle a \rangle$. Indeed, these two complements $\langle b \rangle$ and $\langle ab \rangle$ are never conjugates of one another. So are there any conditions for which $G$ and $N$ must satisfy such that the complement of $N$ if $G$ is unique up to conjugation of $G$? Any reference on literature are very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem? This describes the situation where gcd$(|N|,|G:N|)=1$: then complements exist and all complements are conjugate.

Comment: I'm aware of Schur Zassenhaus theorem. Are there any results other than this?